# OOP Associations philosophical concept

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I'm wondering what are pros and cons between below possibilities of association between classes. I know it's very general question and depends on specific case needs but I 'm wondering in general as philosophical problem what is the difference

1)

```
class Order
{
    IList<OrderPosition> Positions;
}

class OrderPosition
{

}
```

2)

```
class Order
{

}

class OrderPosition
{
    Order Order;
}
```

There is even third option to create bidirectional association but that's waste of memory I guess.

Comment: It absolutely depends on your situation.  This is not a discussion site, please see the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Not always - in that particular situation Order - OrderPosition both cases are equal for me I can't see why I should use one over another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the same.

1) means that an `Order` can have several `OrderPositions` and it does not avoid that an **`OrderPosition` could be found in multiple `Orders`**.

2) means that an `OrderPosition` can only be contained in **one `Order`**.

There are other implications if we talk about ["composition"/"aggregation"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61376/aggregation-vs-composition) (OOP)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are some external factors that prevent a position from being in multiple `Order`s or appearing multiple times in the same `Order` in (1) (because this can't happen in (2)) (as per [polkduran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16399377/1711796))...

It completely depends on the situation - ask yourself what operations are performed the most often and this will point to the desired design.

Use (1) when you need to find all positions of a given `Order` quickly.

Use (2) when you need to find the `Order` of a given position quickly.

Using both is absolutely not wasting memory in many real-world situations where you want to be able to find all positions of a given `Order` and the `Order` of a given positions quickly.

You may want to change (1) to some sort of tree or hash structure, so you're able to find a *specific* position of a given `Order` faster than searching through all positions for the `Order` (if this makes sense in the context of your design).